# how can i decrease scale as i am swipping upward in swift

Tags: swift, uikit, uipangesturerecognizer

i want to decrease scale of uiview as swiping upwards, i want the same animation for closing app like in ios 12 or 13.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPanningFromBottom))
        
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        panGesture.delegate = self
    }
    @objc func didPanningFromBottom(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            print("began")
        }
        else if recognizer.state == .changed {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseOut) {
                self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.25, y: 0.25 )
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? You need to [edit] your question and clearly explain your expected behaviour and how your current code isn't matching that.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i want to drag up to drecrease scale of uiview as my finger goes up uiview decrease its scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

Assuming the rest of your code is intact just swap `didPanningFromBottom`.

Basically there are two things you need to do. First track the drag operation and just move along the view with the finger, scaling it a bit if you want. Second, on release, determine if you should animate away the view or let it bounce back. In my code I check both the velocity and the distance of the release point. You might want to modify the exact values.

You probably also want to check for `.cancel` case to always move back to start position.

```
@objc func didPanningFromBottom(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let yPosition = recognizer.translation(in: view).y
    let yVelocity = recognizer.velocity(in: view).y

    if recognizer.state == .began {

    } else if recognizer.state == .changed {

        // Scale down a small amount
        let scale: CGFloat = 1.0 - abs(yPosition / 2000)
        
        myView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            .translatedBy(x: 0, y: yPosition)
            .scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)

    } else if recognizer.state == .ended {

        // If either have a minimum velocity or release beyond a fixed point
        if yVelocity < -200 || (yVelocity <= 0 && yPosition < 400) {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -self.view.bounds.size.height / 2 - self.myView.bounds.size.height / 2)
                self.myView.alpha = 0
            }
        } else {
            // Move it back to start
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much i really needed that

Comment: @ArbazChughtai don't forget to mark as accepted answer, please.